# How do I turn on the Gamepad's IR without turning on the Wii U itself?

Tags: pc, wii-u, wiimote

I use it to play PC games with a Wiimote, but my main concern is with power usage. I don't like the idea of having both my PC and Wii U taking up electricity.

Comment: I'm confused; what does a Wiimote have to do with the Gamepad?

Comment: I use the wiimote to play games on PC, and the gamepad is required to do that.

If it's a problem, I can have the tag removed.

Comment: How...is the gamepad required?  It's a bluetooth connection.  I think we need more information about your setup.

Comment: Sorry. The gamepad has an IR sensor built directly into the top of it. I power on the Wii U and go to wii mode. Once there, I sync the wiimote to my PC, get my glovepie script loaded, and then I can use the Wiimote combined with the IR from the Gamepad to move the mouse.

Comment: Well, based on your setup, what you want is impossible; the gamepad is linked to the Wii U.  It can't do anything without it.  If you don't want to turn on the Wii U, you need to find a different way to accomplish the syncing without the gamepad.

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer:

You can't.

---

#### Long answer:

You could mod the gamepad to only turn on the gamepad's Sensor Bar, but if you could do that, you'd have significantly better options to choose from.

The "Sensor" Bar, unlike its name implies, doesn't have any sensors at all. It's simply made up of 2 IR lamps. That's it.

The *actual* sensors are in the Wiimote. The Wiimote senses the IR lights emitted by the Sensor Bar, and uses position, size, and distance of the lights to calculate where the cursor should be pointing, its rotation, and distance to the TV.

The Sensor Bar is so simple, in fact, that anybody could simply place two candles in front of the Wiimote, and it would work. Alternatively, two regular lamps would work as well, although they'd have to radiate enough heat for the Wiimote's sensor to pick up.

***A better solution*** would be to use two IR lamps and create your own sensor bar. You can harvest IR lamps from TV remote controls. Or you could buy a Wireless Sensor Bar instead, which can be turned on even with the Wii U turned off.

Comment: You can also use an IR source like a candle.  This is what my friend did to get his working on PC.

Comment: That was mentioned in the answer....